# How i can remove the draw selection by MouseUp?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, selection

i have draw selection in my program to see how much i cut from my picture like in paint and my question is, how i can remove the selection of the area from my picture when i leave the mouse ?

Here my Code :

```
private void ChoosedImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var pen = new Pen(this.selectionBrush);
    pen.Color = Color.Black;

    if (choosedImage.Image != null)
    {
        if (Rect != null && Rect.Width > 0 && Rect.Height > 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Rect);
        }
    }
}
private void ChoosedImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        return;

    var tempEndPoint = e.Location;
    Rect.Location = new Point(
            Math.Min(this.seleciontStartPoint.X, tempEndPoint.X),
            Math.Min(this.seleciontStartPoint.Y, tempEndPoint.Y));

    Rect.Size = new Size(
            Math.Abs(this.seleciontStartPoint.X - tempEndPoint.X),
            Math.Abs(this.seleciontStartPoint.Y - tempEndPoint.Y));
    choosedImage.Invalidate();

}
```

I tried to invalidate the graphic by mouseUp but it not works. So i have no idea how i can handle it by mouseUp

Comment: Simply set the Rect to be null or have a zero size! - Notes: 1) you leak a Pen 2) for pen.width=1 use Pens.color 3) the word id 'chosen' not 'choosed'..

Comment: Use Graphics.FromImage() to start modifying the actual image.  Call choosedImage.Invalidate() when you are done so the pbox repaints itself.